# how can I access iframe.contentDocument to get response after cross-origin request?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I'm successfully sending a file from `localhost:8888` to `localhost:8080` (different domain in production), but I can't read the HTTP response after the transfer finishes.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8888" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8080". The frame requesting access set
>   "document.domain" to "localhost", but the frame being accessed did
>   not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow
>   access.

To send the file, for compatibility support, I'm trying to get this to work for `<form>` based file uploads; not `XHR` based. This is the basic HTML structure:

```
<form target="file-iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="invalid">
  <input type="file" id="file-input" class="file-input" title="select files">
</form>
<iframe src="javascript:false;" id="file-iframe" name="file-iframe"></iframe>
```

To insert the `<iframe>` element into the DOM, I do the following:

```
document.domain = document.domain;
var domainHack = 'javascript:document.write("<script type=text/javascript>document.domain=document.domain;</script>")';

var html = '<iframe id="file-iframe" name="file-iframe"></iframe>';
var parent = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var iframe = UTILS.createDomElement(html, parent);
iframe.src = domainHack;

UTILS.attachEvent(iframe, 'load', function(e) {

  // this throws the above SecurityError
  var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

  // do other stuff...
});
```

Before I submit the form, I set the `action` attribute on the `<form>` to be the target cross-domain URL:

```
action="http://localhost:8080/"
```

After submitting the `<form>`, the `<iframe>`'s `load` event is fired, and I try to access the `<iframe>`'s content to read the HTTP response. However, doing so throws the above error since this is is a cross-origin request, and I don't have access to the `<iframe>`'s content.

I thought the `document.domain` hack would work, but the error message is telling me that the `iframe` did not set the domain to `localhost`, even though I set the `iframe`'s `src` attribute to the `domainHack` variable, which seems to execute.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? How can I set `document.domain` to be `localhost` for both the `<iframe>` and its parent (which is the current page).

---

I've read through several StackOverflow questions, some MDN articles, and other random results on Google, but I haven't been able to get this to work. Some stuff I've looked through already:

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Did you tried postMessage which is mentioned in your first link "Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy"?

Comment: Check this link, I have written blog for this kind of problem https://crossdomainjavascript.wordpress.com/author/sandeeproop/

Comment: @Sandeeproop... yes, I tried `postMessage()`. messaging works, but the problem is that I need the iframe's content, which I don't have access to since `contentWindow` throws the error.... so `postMessage()` is useless unless I can get the iframe's content

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to exactly the same problem

Comment: Well we might follow all wrong way. var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; This is how it is designed to be. PostMessage must happened from the iframe itself. According to a friend to make this work we have to send html from the server (not json), with a function that will evaluate on the client and do the real postMessage.

Comment: @user732456... I figured out a way to do what I want. I'll post an update with my solution later today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around to try and figure this out, I finally came across a solution that seems to work for me. However, it isn't an exact answer to my question.

In summary, I'm working on supporting `<form>` based file uploads. For browsers that do not support file upload via `XHR`, we have to resort to the traditional `<form>` submission, using a hidden `<iframe>` to avoid page refresh. The form redirects the reload action into the hidden `<iframe>`, and then the HTTP response is written to the body of the `<iframe>` after the file has been transferred.

Due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and hence the reason I asked this question, I don't have access to the `<iframe>`'s content. The same-origin policy for `<iframe>`s restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. Since we can't get access to the `<iframe>`'s document, which is where the file upload HTTP response gets written to, the server will return a redirect response to which the server will append the upload response JSON. When the `<iframe>` loads, the JS will parse out the response JSON, and write it to the `<iframe>`'s body. Finally, since the redirect was to the same origin, we can access the `<iframe>`'s contents :)

A huge thanks to [jQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload); they did all the hard work ;)

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads

### Setting Up...

**JS**

```
function setupForm() {

  // form is declared outside of this scope
  form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('id', 'upload-form');
  form.setAttribute('target', 'target-iframe');
  form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
  form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');

  // set the 'action' attribute before submitting the form
  form.setAttribute('action', 'invalid');
};

function setupIframe() {

  // iframe is declared outside of this scope
  iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  /*
   * iframe needs to have the 'name' attribute set so that some versions of
   * IE and Firefox 3.6 don't open a new window/tab 
   */
  iframe.id = 'target-iframe';
  iframe.name = 'target-iframe';

  /*
   * "javascript:false" as initial iframe src to prevent warning popups on
   * HTTPS in IE6
   */
  iframe.src = 'javascript:false;';
  iframe.style.display = 'none';

  $(iframe).bind('load', function() {
    $(iframe)
      .unbind('load')
      .bind('load', function() {
        try {

          /*
           * the HTTP response will have been written to the body of the iframe.
           * we're assuming the server appended the response JSON to the URL,
           * and did the redirect correctly
           */
          var content = $(iframe).contents().find("body").html();
          response = $.parseJSON(content);

          if (!response) {
            // handle error
            return;
          }

          uploadFile(...); // upload the next file
        }
        catch (e) {
          // handle error
        }
      });
  });

  /*
   * insert the iframe as a sibling to the form. I don't think it really
   * matters where the iframe is on the page
   */
  $(form).after(iframe);
};
```

**HTML -  redirect page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // grabs the JSON from the end of the URL
      document.body.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.slice(1));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only thing left to do is set the `action` attribute on the `<form>` to the cross-domain URL that we're sending the upload to:

```
form.setAttribute('action', 'http://sub.example.com:8080/upload?id=ab123');
form.submit();
```

### Meanwhile, on the server...

```
// send redirect to the iframe redirect page, where the above HTML lives
// generates URL: http://example.com/hack?%7B%22error%22%3Afalse%2C%22status%22%3A%22success%22%7D
response.sendRedirect("http://example.com/hack?{\"error\":false,\"status\":\"success\"}");
```

I know this is a massive hack to get around the same-origin policy with `<iframe>`s, but it seems to work, and I think it's pretty good with cross-browser compatibility. I haven't tested it in all  browsers, but I'll get around to doing that, and post an update.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I came to solution also. It's a bit hard coded atm, but still looks neat.

First I made an html file on the server. (I'll modify it to ejs template later, that includes my data).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        parent.postMessage('Some message!!!', 'http://192.168.0.105:3001'); // hard coded, will change this later
    }

    window.onload=myFunction;
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Important part here is the use of parent.

Than from my node server I'm uploading the file and sending back to the client the html file:

```
res.sendFile('file.html');
```

On the client I have the same html like you.

```
'<form id="{id}_form" action="http://192.168.0.105:3011/private/profile_picture/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="{id}_uploadframe">',
'<span id="{id}_wrapper" class="file-wrapper">',
    '<input id="{id}_real" type="file" accept="image/*" name="photo" />',
    '<span class="button">{0}</span>',
'</span>',
'</form>',
'<iframe id="{id}_uploadframe" name="{id}_uploadframe" class="mc-hidden"></iframe>',
```

This template I rendered on the page. I added the following event Handler also

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    //if(event.origin !== cross_domain) return;
    console.log('message received:  ' + event.data,event);
},false);
```

As you know addEventListener is not working on all browsers. And this solution will not work on IE8 < 8, which does not support postMessage. Hope this is hapefull to you